# My login code loops me back instead of logging me in

Tags: php

I'm trying to make my system not able to go to my indextemplate.php (main page) without logging in first.

I've learned that `$_SESSION` is the perfect thing for it. However, I'm having quite a bit of problem with it.

Instead of logging me in, it just loops back to my index1.php (login page) without any error.

Here's my db code for my login page:

```
<?php
try {
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=login', "root", "");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}

$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `uid` = :uid AND `pwd` = :pwd";
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$userData = [
'uid'=>$uid,
'pwd'=>$pwd,
];

$statement->execute($userData);

if($statement->rowCount() > 0){
$_SESSION['logged'] = true;
header('Location: indextemplate.php');
exit();
}

elseif(empty($uid&$pwd)){
header('Location: index1.php?error=empty1');
exit();
}
elseif ($uid!=$idvariable&$pwd!=$idvarible){
header('Location: index1.php?error=empty2');
exit();
}

?>
```

and here's the code for my indextemplate (main page):

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged'])){
header('location:index1.php');
}
else
{ 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<?php include 'Header.php';

?>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default top-navbar" role="navigation">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data- toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="Indextemplate.php"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i><strong> JADE HOTEL </strong></a>
        </div>

<ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false">
<i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-messages">
<li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <strong>John Doe</strong>
                                <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                    <em>Today</em>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s...</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <strong>John Smith</strong>
                                <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                    <em>Yesterday</em>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since an kwilnw...</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <strong>John Smith</strong>
                                <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                    <em>Yesterday</em>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the...</div>
                        </a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-center" href="#">
                            <strong>Read All Messages</strong>
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /.dropdown-messages -->
            </li>
            <!-- /.dropdown -->
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-tasks">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <p>
                                    <strong>Task 1</strong>
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted">60% Complete</span>
                                </p>
                                <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%">
                                        <span class="sr-only">60% Complete (success)</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <p>
                                    <strong>Task 2</strong>
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted">28% Complete</span>
                                </p>
                                <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="28" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 28%">
                                        <span class="sr-only">28% Complete</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <p>
                                    <strong>Task 3</strong>
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted">60% Complete</span>
                                </p>
                                <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%">
                                        <span class="sr-only">60% Complete (warning)</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <p>
                                    <strong>Task 4</strong>
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted">85% Complete</span>
                                </p>
                                <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="85" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 85%">
                                        <span class="sr-only">85% Complete (danger)</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-center" href="#">
                            <strong>See All Tasks</strong>
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /.dropdown-tasks -->
            </li>
            <!-- /.dropdown -->
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="fa fa-bell fa-fw"></i> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-alerts">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <i class="fa fa-comment fa-fw"></i> New Comment
                                <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 min</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i> 3 New Followers
                                <span class="pull-right text-muted small">12 min</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i> Message Sent
                                <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 min</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i> New Task
                                <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 min</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <i class="fa fa-upload fa-fw"></i> Server Rebooted
                                <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 min</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-center" href="#">
                            <strong>See All Alerts</strong>
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /.dropdown-alerts -->
            </li>
            <!-- /.dropdown -->
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> User Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i> Settings</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="logout.php"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /.dropdown-user -->
            </li>
            <!-- /.dropdown -->
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!--/. NAV TOP  -->
    <nav class="navbar-default navbar-side" role="navigation">
    <div id="sideNav" href=""><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></div>
        <div class="sidebar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav" id="main-menu">

                <li>
                    <a class="active-menu" href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="ChartTemplate.php"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Charts</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="DatabaseTemplate.php"><i class="fa fa-table"></i> Database</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="FormTemplate.php"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Forms </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="BlankPageTemplate.php"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-file"></i> Empty Page</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>

    </nav>
    <!-- /. NAV SIDE  -->
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div id="page-inner">


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h1 class="page-header">
                        Dashboard
                    </h1>
                    <ol class="breadcrumb">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Library</a></li>
<li class="active">Data</li>
</ol>
                </div>
            </div>


            <!-- /. ROW  -->

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary text-center no-boder bg-color-green green">
                        <div class="panel-left pull-left green">
                            <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-5x"></i>

                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-right pull-right">
                            <h3>8,457</h3>
                           <strong> Daily Visits</strong>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary text-center no-boder bg-color-blue blue">
                          <div class="panel-left pull-left blue">
                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-5x"></i>
                            </div>

                        <div class="panel-right pull-right">
                        <h3>52,160 </h3>
                           <strong> Sales</strong>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary text-center no-boder bg-color-red red">
                        <div class="panel-left pull-left red">
                            <i class="fa fa fa-comments fa-5x"></i>

                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-right pull-right">
                         <h3>15,823 </h3>
                           <strong> Comments </strong>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary text-center no-boder bg-color-brown brown">
                        <div class="panel-left pull-left brown">
                            <i class="fa fa-users fa-5x"></i>

                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-right pull-right">
                        <h3>36,752 </h3>
                         <strong>No. of Visits</strong>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Line Chart
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div id="morris-line-chart"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
                </div>      
            </div> 


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body easypiechart-panel">
                    <h4>Customers</h4>
                    <div class="easypiechart" id="easypiechart-blue" data-percent="82" ><span class="percent">82%</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body easypiechart-panel">
                    <h4>Sales</h4>
                    <div class="easypiechart" id="easypiechart-orange" data-percent="55" ><span class="percent">55%</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body easypiechart-panel">
                    <h4>Profits</h4>
                    <div class="easypiechart" id="easypiechart-teal" data-percent="84" ><span class="percent">84%</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body easypiechart-panel">
                    <h4>No. of Visits</h4>
                    <div class="easypiechart" id="easypiechart-red" data-percent="46" ><span class="percent">46%</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--/.row-->


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            Bar Chart Example
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div id="morris-bar-chart"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            Donut Chart Example
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div id="morris-donut-chart"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          Area Chart
 </div>
<div class="panel-body">
      <div id="morris-area-chart"></div>
        </div>
          </div>  
            </div>      
              </div>    
<!-- /. ROW  -->            
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
           <div class="panel-heading">
        Tasks Panel
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
       <div class="list-group">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
         <span class="badge">7 minutes ago</span>
             <i class="fa fa-fw fa-comment"></i> Commented on a post
</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
      <span class="badge">16 minutes ago</span>
         <i class="fa fa-fw fa-truck"></i> Order 392 shipped
</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item">
     <span class="badge">36 minutes ago</span>
         <i class="fa fa-fw fa-globe"></i> Invoice 653 has paid
</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item">
       <span class="badge">1 hour ago</span>
           <i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> A new user has been added
</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item">
       <span class="badge">1.23 hour ago</span>
         <i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> A new user has added
</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item">
       <span class="badge">yesterday</span>
         <i class="fa fa-fw fa-globe"></i> Saved the world
</a>
</div>
<div class="text-right">
        <a href="#">More Tasks <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-heading">
         Responsive Table Example
</div> 
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-striped table- bordered table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>S No.</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>User Name</th>
<th>Email ID.</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
<td>John15482</td>
<td>name@site.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>Kimsila</td>
<td>Marriye</td>
<td>Kim1425</td>
<td>name@site.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>Rossye</td>
<td>Nermal</td>
<td>Rossy1245</td>
<td>name@site.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>Richard</td>
<td>Orieal</td>
<td>Rich5685</td>
<td>name@site.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5</td>
<td>Jacob</td>
<td>Hielsar</td>
<td>Jac4587</td>
<td>name@site.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>6</td>
<td>Wrapel</td>
<td>Dere</td>
<td>Wrap4585</td>
<td>name@site.com</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /. ROW  -->
<footer></footer>
</div>
<!-- /. PAGE INNER  -->
</div>
<!-- /. PAGE WRAPPER  -->
</div>    
<?php include 'Scripts.php' ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php 
} 
?>
```

Comment: **never ever ever ever** store plain text passwords! use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`

Comment: @FranzGleichmann don't worry. I will hash it. This is just for testing out first.

Comment: you should *start* by hashing. there's no reason to push security off to the future, that's how unsafe programs are born.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann thanks! I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start session when you are setting session variables.

```
if($statement->rowCount() > 0){
session_start();
$_SESSION['logged'] = true;
header('Location: indextemplate.php');
exit();
}
```

This will work.

**Explanation :** If you will not start session then `$_SESSION['logged']` variable won't set itself value as true. So you need to start session before setting session variable. There is other solution like add `session_start();` in top of page, but it's not good, because it will start session if user is not valid.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I've been missing all along.

Comment: If it's satisfied your requirement, you can accept as answer. @E.Cristoph

Comment: I will, in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

start session at the top of login code page.So that the value can be set to the session.
In your case, the session is not started,so it keeps looping to the same page

`session_start();`